# Recursive identity

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Let $n\in {1,...,N}$ and

$q(n)=\frac{1}{2}(q(n-1)+q(n+1))$.

Furthemore $q(0)=1$ and $q(N+1)=1$.
Prove that $q(n)=1$ for all $n\in \{1,...,N\}$. My first idea was to try induction over N and I can do the base case N=1. But the induction step is difficult. Is there an easier way to prove this or do I have to do it by induction?

Comment: Rewrite this as $q(n)-q(n-1)=q(n+1)-q(n)$ and now define $s(n)=q(n)-q(n-1)$ to get $s(n)=s(n+1)$. So $s(n)$ is some constant sequence. See if you can proceed from here.

Comment: Thanks four your help. My idea would be to show that $s(n)=0$ and because of that for all n $q(n)=q(n+1)$ and because $q(N+1)=1$, $q(n)=1$ for all n. But im having troulbe showing $s(n)=0$. Could you elobarate your idea a little more ?

Comment: Can you express $s(1)+s(2)+\dotsb+s(N+1)=q(\star)-q(\star)$ ? Also we know that $s(n)=c$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a complete answer using the hints from Anurag A, consider the sequence $s(n) = q(n) - q(n-1)$. We can rearrange the given relation to be:
$$
2q(n) - q(n-1) = q(n+1) \quad \implies \quad q(n) - q(n-1) = q(n+1) - q(n) \quad \implies \quad s(n) = s(n+1)
$$
This holds for all $n \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$, so $s: \{1, 2, \ldots N\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a constant sequence, say $s(n) = C$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, \ldots N\}$. Then, by considering the sum of the telescoping series, we have:
$$
C \cdot N = \sum_{n = 1}^N s(n) = \sum_{n = 1}^N q(n) - q(n-1) = -q(0) + q(N) = -1 + 1 = 0
$$
Thus, we have that $C \cdot N = 0$, and by the structure of your question we assume that $N \neq 0$ which means we must have $C = 0$. Therefore, $s$ is the identically zero sequence which means that $q(n) = q(n-1)$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$. $\square$

Comment: I think it holds for all $n\in \{1,..,N+1\}$ because by Definition $q(N+1)=0$ and not $q(N)=0$.